# Exchange 2016 mail flow rule sending email but, ???question marks appear instead of arabic

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, exchange-2016, encoding

I have added a rule to block users from sending mail to any outside mail service like Outlook, Gmail,Yahoo, etc.

The rule I applied sends an email to the sender, notifying that mail cannot be sent outside the organization, but the message is in Arabic.

It does sent the email but the Arabic text is not visible and shows question marks instead.

At the bottom of the mail is written :
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary.

So is this the issue? How to solve this?

Note: I am using OWA (Webiste) to log in to the account and not any mail client like outlook 2016, etc.

Comment: i had the exact same issue...i hope somebody here know how to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried checking the web browser's character encoding? Try manually setting the page to load in UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Can it work on OWA?  Does this happen to all users?

In exchange server side, I found a similar [case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/223f9b0d-368b-4b70-9942-e800eee5b9fd/question-marks-instead-of-hebrew?forum=Exch2016MFSM), it provides a solution is running this following command: Set-RemoteDomain default -TNEFEnabled $false

In outlook client side, here are some discussion about this issue for your reference.[Why Outlook email messages show unreadable characters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/2cfbd9b3-e9d5-4230-8863-a68b354b2c8e/why-outlook-email-messages-show-unreadable-characters?forum=outlook)

Comment: thanks for your time....but this did not help me

Comment: I am opening the mail in OWA (Website) and not on outlook client or any mail client.

Comment: The solution seems to be proposed in this case.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/31b647a5-e701-4a84-a354-14c81dea901b/transport-rule-massage-language?forum=exchangesvrgeneral